# Default checked not work when after changing selection

Tags: reactjs

I have popup with three radio buttons and one option is checked by default.
The problem is when I select any option that is not default, close the popup and open again then previously selected option is still checked, but not the default one. 
Please suggest how to keep the default option checked on each popup opening?

1. Popup component

```
var PopupComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {typed: 'all'};
    },

    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({typed: e.target.value});
    },

    handleClick: function(e) {
        // button click handler logic

        $("#alert-modal").modal('hide'); // hide popup
        $('.modal-container')[0].style.display = "none"; 
    },

    render: function() {
        var options = this.props.options;
        var defaultOptIndex = this.props.checkedIndex;
        var radioItems=[];

        for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
            radioItems.push(
                <div key={i} className="modal__radio-group-item">
                    <label><input value={options[i].value} type="radio" name="radio" defaultChecked={defaultOptIndex == i} /> <span /> {options[i].string}</label>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return(
            <div className="modal modal--active">
            <div className="modal__content" style={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 540, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                <p className="modalTitle">{this.props.title}</p>
                <div className="modal__radio-group" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    {radioItems}
                </div>
                <div className="modal__buttons-container">
                    <button className="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>{R('continue_button')}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

2. The function is showing the popup

```
function showPopup(header_title, options, checkedIndex, func, index) {
    ReactDOM.render(<PopupComponent title={header_title} options={options} checkedIndex={checkedIndex} callback={func} provider_index={index} />, document.getElementById('alert-modal'));
    $('.modal-container')[0].style.display = "flex";
    $("#alert-modal").modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are just closing popup in  handleClick(), you can update state to the default value in handleClick() using setState();

Comment: that makes sense, but not sure what I have to set in handleClick() using setState() in order to set default option checked.

Comment: like this:-      this.setState({typed:"default value"});